# SQL Creating a function to get the sum based on column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to write a simple function that will allow me to get the sum based off the value of a column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GetSumOfColumnByCase](@column varchar(50), @case int)
    RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    declare @return int
    set @return = SUM(CASE WHEN @column = @case THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

    -- Return the result of the function
    return @return

END
GO
```

I call this function like this:

```
        SELECT HouseDescription,
               [dbo].[GetSumOfColumnByCase]([HouseTypeId], 1) AS "houseType1",
               [dbo].[GetSumOfColumnByCase]([HouseTypeId], 2) AS "houseType2"
```

Doing things this way forces me to `GROUP BY` both the houseDescription and the HouseTypeId columns but i just want to `GROUP BY` the housedescription.

If i do things this way:

```
SELECT HouseDescription,
       SUM(CASE WHEN HouseTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "houseType1",
       SUM(CASE WHEN HouseTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "houseType2"
```

Its fine, it doesnt force me to `GROUP BY` HouseTypeId.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: You basically cannot do this in SQL Server.  To handle a variable column, you need dynamic SQL.  A function cannot readily run dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a `GROUP BY` clause, every column needs to either be in the GROUP BY, or it needs to be aggregated.

In your second example, you are fulfilling these requirements - by placing the `SUM` around the function call.  In your first example, since the function call itself isn't wrapped in an aggregation (`SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`, etc.), you must place it in the GROUP BY clause in order to not trigger an error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

I agree with Gordon though, you may want to rethink your strategy for this.

Comment: This is the answer.   The SUM is in the function and not in the main query.

Comment: @John Thompson, Thanks John this makes a lot of sense and spot on Ive reworked my function to use just the case statement and placed the aggregate before the function call. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with a function, because SQL Server does not support dynamic SQL (readily) in functions.  And to handle *any* column, you would need dynamic SQL.

But, you don't need that anyway.  If you want the sum on each row of the original data, you want window functions:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN HouseTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS houseType1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN HouseTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS houseType2
. . .
```

Aggregation is not needed for this query.

Comment: Look closely at the function.   I don't think this is the answer.   He's not trying to do dynamic sql in a function.   He's passing the value, not the column name.   The use of `@column` as the parameter name is deceptive.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks Gordon, this is an interesting topic. Johns answer has helped me to rework my function so that i dont need to group by HouseTypeId.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . The code says `@column = @case` and the example appears to want to do what a windows function does.

Comment: A windows function may be a good solution, but this answer doesn't correctly address the question, "Can anyone explain why this is?"